# Is there a way to combine d3 json variables?

Tags: javascript, json, d3.js

I have the following code below:

```
    var node = svg.selectAll(".node")
          .data(graph.nodes)
          .enter()
          .append("circle")
          .attr("class", "node")
          .attr("r", 20)
          .style("fill", function(d) { return color(d.group); })
          .call(force.drag)
          .style("visibility", function(d) {
            return d.group == 1 ? "hidden" : "visible";
          })
          .on("mouseover", function(d) {
            if(d.group == 2) {
              node.filter(function(d) { return d.group == 1; }).style("visibility", "visible");
              link.filter(function(d) { return d.value == 2; }).style("visibility", "visible");
            }
          }).on("mouseout", function(d) {
            if(d.group == 2) {
              node.filter(function(d) { return d.group == 1; }).style("visibility", "hidden");
              link.filter(function(d) { return d.value == 2; }).style("visibility", "hidden");
          }
        });

var texts = svg.selectAll("text.label")
                .data(graph.nodes)
                .enter().append("text")
                .attr("class", "label")
                .attr("fill", "black")
                .text(function(d) {  return d.name;  });
```

I want to combine the two variables node and texts to move the mouseover effects to the combination. Is this possible? If so, how? Thanks!

Comment: Put things that are being repeated into a function and call the function multiple time...

Comment: I need an example. I'm newer to this

Comment: I figured this out myself. Thanks though~!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I believe you could chain with `filter`. I.e,

```
var node = svg.selectAll(".node").filter("text.label")
```

Comment: Would I remove the text variable and the text addition to the force.on at the bottom?

Comment: I'm afraid it isn't clear to me what you're trying to accomplish, so I really couldn't say.

Answer (score 0):

```
.on("mouseover", function(d) {
            if(d.group == 2) {
               changeVisibility("visible")
            }
          }).on("mouseout", function(d) {
            if(d.group == 2) {
              changeVisibility("hidden")
          }


function changeVisisbility(visibility){
      node.filter(function(d) { return d.group == 1; }).style("visibility", visibility);
      link.filter(function(d) { return d.value == 2; }).style("visibility", visibility);
}
```

Comment: These relate to the node and the link. They don't link to the text